# 'str' object has no attribute 'chunks'

Tags: django, mongodb, chunks

I have this error when try to save image in folder and in mongo db
how i can solve it

```py
def save_img_field(value):

    # Save image file to the static/img folder
    image_path = save_image_to_folder(value)

    # Save image to MongoDB using GridFS
    image_id = fs.put(value, filename=value, content_type=value.content_type)

    # Return the image id and path for storage in MongoDB and Django folder
    return {'id': str(image_id), 'path': image_path}


def save_image_to_folder(value):
    # Create the file path to save the image in the Django static/img folder
    image_name = value
    image_path = f'decapolis/static/img/{image_name}'

    # Open the image file and save it to the folder
    with open(image_path, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in value.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

    # Return the image path
    return image_path
```

am try to solve it in many way but not working

Comment: What is `value`? Apparently it's a string.

Comment: please update the question instead of commenting here with code.

Comment: the value is either an image or text value

Comment: There's your problem then, if it's a text value then `chunks` is not an operation you can call on it.

Answer (score 0):

While saving to a file, add check wheter it is a string or an image:

```py
with open(image_path, 'wb+') as destination:
    if type(value) == str:
        destination.write(value.encode())   # or whatever you actually want to do if it's a string
    else:
        for chunk in value.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Comment: when wirte your code show this error 

 destination.write(value)  # or whatever you actually want to do if it's a string
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'


@NixonSparrow

Comment: Then change to `destination.write(value.encode())`.